# Putnam and Beyond: Question #475, real analysis help

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So the problem is:
Let $f\colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that 
$$\int_{0}^ {1} f(x)\,dx= \int_{0} ^{1} xf(x)\,dx = 1.$$

Prove that $$\int_{0} ^ {1} f^2(x)\,dx \geq 4.$$

The solution is given in the book but I simply don't understand it at all.

Could anyone walk me through how this is done?

So the proof goes like this:

1). We find that f(x) = 6x-2 satisfies this(I'm not sure how this was found)

2). $\int_{0} ^ {1} (f(x) - g(x)) dx= \int_{0}^{1} x(f(x)-g(x))dx= 0$

3). Considering the linear combination of two integrals, we get(I don't get why they did this)

$\int_{0} ^ {1} p(x)(f(x) - g(x))dx = 0.$

4). Now we have(I don't understand this part at all)

0 $\leq$ $\int_{0} ^ {1} (f(x) - g(x))^2 dx = \int_{0} ^ {1} f(x)(f(x) - g(x))dx-\int_{0} ^ {1} g(x)(f(x) - g(x))dx = \int_{0} ^ {1} f^2(x) - f(x)g(x)dx$

$= \int_{0} ^{1} f^2(x)dx - 6\int_{0} ^ {1} xf(x) dx + 2\int_{0} ^ {1} f(x)dx = \int_{0} ^ {1} f^2(x)dx - 4.$

Comment: If you want us to walk  you through a proof you should include the proof, and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @EthanBolker you're right, I'll include it.

Comment: This has also been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519421/show-that-int-01-f2xdx-geq-3-if-f0-1-to-mathbbr-is-an-integrable) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158236/an-inequality-involving-integrals).

Comment: @Mattos thanks, didn't realize!

Comment: There are typos in what you wrote, and at least one key word missing. Maybe that's why you are not following the argument? For instance, in 1), instead of $f$ you want to write $g$. in 3), $p$ is any *linear* polynomial (in particular, the result holds with $p=g$, since $g$ itself is linear).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what the proof in the book is, but I have a solution which you may or may not like.  It is slightly high level, in that it is motivated by inner product spaces, but it can easily be translated into pure calculus.

Define an inner product on $C[0,1]$ (continuous functions on the interval) by $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 fg dx$.  We are given that $\langle f,1 \rangle = \langle f, x \rangle =1$.  The key idea is that if we write a given $f$ as $f=f^{\parallel}+f^{\perp}$, where $f^{\parallel}$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the span of $1$ and $x$, then $<f,f>=<f^{\parallel},f^{\parallel}>+<f^{\perp},f^{\perp}>$, two non-negative terms.  However, our given conditions are enough for us to determine $f^{\parallel}$ (it will be the same for any $f$ satisfying the given conditions), and hence we will get both the minimum value of $<f,f>$ AND the particular $f$ that causes the minimum.

While we could use Grahm-Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis for the $\operatorname{Span}(\{1,x\})$ and compute the projection that way, it is easier for us to just write $f^{\parallel}=a+bx$.  Then our given conditions are that $\langle a+bx,1\rangle = a+b/2 = 1$ and $\langle a+bx, x \rangle =a/2+b/3=1$.  Solving the system, we have $b=6, a=-2$.  Hence $f^{\parallel}=6x-2$. and so $\langle f,f \rangle \geq \int_0^1 (6x-2)^2 = 4$.

Comment: I really like your answer. Thank you, it's appreciated :)

Comment: Just trying to understand further here, are b=6 and a=-2 the only solutions to that system, or are there more?

Comment: @JoshSteier Yes, they are the only solution.  We have two (linear) equations in two unknowns, so unless one of the equations is redundant or the equations are contradictory (which they are not), you would expect there to be a unique solution.  But in general, with systems of linear equations, there are $0$, $1$, or an infinite number of solutions.