# If the $\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx =\int_{0}^1 xf(x)dx = 1$, find the minimum value of $I = \int_{0}^1 f^2(x) dx$, without using Hilbert spaces.

Tags: calculus

Now, I started by completing the square of the expression $f(x)-\lambda x$ where $\lambda$ is some constant and integrating this, thereby obtaining an expression for $I$, in terms of $\lambda$. I am unable to proceed further.

Apparently, I am able to obtain the answer for this once I assume a polynomial function - specifically, a linear function - but I don't understand why the minimum value of I will be attained for a linear function only.

Comment: Please learn *MathJax* as your title is very hard to understand.

Comment: It looks like you haven't stated the assumption. What are you assuming about the functions? Are they continuous or differentiable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putnam and Beyond: Question #475, real analysis help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303498/putnam-and-beyond-question-475-real-analysis-help) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E1f(x)%3D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E1xf(x)%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24I%3D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E1f%5E2(x)dx%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aminimum&p=1). Also, through a duplicate deleted question, there's ...

Comment: (cont.) [Show that $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx\geq 3$, if $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function s.t. $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=1$](/q/1519421). In addition, there's many AoPS threads, e.g., [Definite Integral estimation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h412229p2314112), [Integral of f^2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1447334p8276974), [Minimum value of f(x)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1617803p10118264), [Minjmum of integration](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1632366p10251782), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Even if you don't want to hear about Hilbert spaces, the easy way to show this is to establish the equality $||f||^2 = ||f^\parallel||^2 + ||f^\perp||^2$ in this special case, and the general case is not that harder (or even different).